# Samsung sph-m510 not charging

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung sph-m510 that I recently got a new battery for and it was working fine until one day after leaving it untouched for about a week I went to charge it and it wouldn't charge it just got really hot. Does anyone know what is going wrong?